# GAE/GCP deployment via Github

Tags: git, google-app-engine, web, github, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google App Engine / Google Cloud Platform unpaid, as I have been for many many years. Now, after the upgrade to the newest interface, I am unable to use the GCloud SDK (installed locally) to deploy anything to my projects, and while I have tried to solve a few issues, more keep popping up. So I've switched over to using GitHub. I successfully linked my GitHub repository to the GitHub app on my machine, and to the GCP "Source Code" page.

[image: Google Developers Console]

However, the source code shown here does not reflect the page itself. When I visit the main "*.appspot.com" domain for my site, the updated site is the old one, and has not been updated to the new one, which I just pushed about an hour ago. In addition to committing and syncing changes, is there anything else I need to do to get my GitHub repository's code to reflect what shows up on the site itself?

Comment: I solved my personal issue with GAE, but it's simply avoiding GitHub. If anyone has any solutions, I'd still be up for them!

Comment: Could you clarify what state this issue is in? Did you succeed to deploy using the SDK? What steps did you follow to link your repository to your project? Did you configure a release pipeline? You can find the instructions for Push-to-Deploy [in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy).

Comment: I succeeded in deploying using the SDK after rewriting much of my site to use a different language (Python 2.7 instead of PHP). I linked my repository by using the feature built-in under "Source Code" on "console.developers.google.com". I do not pay or intend to use the trial version of GCP, so I do not have access to "Click to Deploy". For the same reason, I can't use Jenkins Push-to-Deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you linked your cloud repository without setting up a push-to-deploy pipeline as described [in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy). For this reason, pushing to your repo may update the source browse feature's view, but won't actually trigger a deployment.

I'm glad to hear everything is working for you at any rate, having gone a different route of deploying normally with the SDK and using python, and we both understand the cause of the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to use the Jenkins push-to-deploy without either a trial or paying for GCP?

Comment: No, as it requires you to spin up a Jenkins compute instance to manage the build and deployment when you push.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks anyways for the tip!