# Using files from GitHub repository in App Engine

Tags: html, eclipse, git, google-app-engine, github

I recently began using App Engine to deploy a few web applications. I am using Eclipse and installed Google's plugin to deploy my application. All of my files for the web application are saved in a repository.

Whenever I update/deploy a web app build I copy/paste the HTML source code into the html file in the raw folder of my Web Application Project Folder and "Deploy to App Engine".

I would like to know how I can go about connecting/syncing my HTML file within GitHub in Eclipse so I don't have to copy/paste the source code every time I deploy a new build.

Comment: I have no idea why you're copying and pasting code. Why don't you clone the repository from Github?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE/GCP deployment via Github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443943/gae-gcp-deployment-via-github)